# Replacing whole string is faster than replacing only its first character

Tags: python, regex, time

I tried to replace a character `a` by `b` in a given large string. I did an experiment - first I replaced it in the whole string, then I replaced it only at its beginning.

```py
import re
# pattern = re.compile('a')
pattern = re.compile('^a')
string = 'x' * 100000

pattern.sub('b', string)
```

I expected that replacing the beginning would have to be much faster then replacing the whole string because you have to check only 1 position instead of 100000. I did some measuring:

```
python -m timeit --setup "import re; p=re.compile('a'); string='x'*100000" "p.sub('b', string)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.1 usec per loop
```

```
python -m timeit --setup "import re; p=re.compile('^a'); string='x'*100000" "p.sub('b', string)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 613 usec per loop
```

The results show that, on the contrary, trying to replace the whole string is about 30x faster. Would you expect such result? Can you explain that?

Comment: What times do you get if you search for a Chinese character instead of 'a'?

Comment: @KellyBundy `^解` takes 606 usec per loop, `解` and `解$` take 0.148 usec. I hope it's Chinese. For some terrifying reason it is waay faster than for the letter `a`.

Comment: Weird. On my machine, search without an anchor (for `'\u9999'`) is *even faster* than match; the versions with an anchor are unaffected. There is clearly a lot more to this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The underlying string implementation is likely memory optimized if it contains only ASCII characters (i.e. 1 byte per character). When searching for a character that uses more space, it probably checks first whether this is possible at all, and if the to-be-searched string contains only ASCII, it just shortcuts. The implementation of [`sre_search`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/_sre.c#L610) differentiates between 1, 2 and 4 byte character sizes of the target string. You can check that `sys.getsizeof('x'*1000 + '\u9999')` uses 2x memory as just `'x'*1001`.

Comment: Doesn't need to be Chinese, just wanted a multibyte-character string.

Comment: It's probably [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/sre_lib.h#L1427) that shortcuts if the literal exceeds the character width of the target string.

Comment: As usual, I'd recommend PyPi regex library (`pip install regex` and then `import regex`) instead. `re` should be used with a lot of caution.

Comment: @a_guest Ah, right. Since Python uses a flexible storage scheme, promoting to wider characters only when necessary, it can very quickly check that the string does not contain wider characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions provided in the Python `re` module do not optimize based on anchors. In particular, functions that try to apply a regex at every position - `.search`, `.sub`, `.findall` etc. - will do so even when the regex can only possibly match at the beginning. I.e., even without multi-line mode specified, such that `^` can only match at the beginning of the string, the call is not re-routed internally. Thus:

```sh
$ # .match only looks at the first position regardless
$ python -m timeit --setup "import re; p=re.compile('a'); string='x'*100000" "p.match(string)"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 155 nsec per loop
$ python -m timeit --setup "import re; p=re.compile('^a'); string='x'*100000" "p.match(string)"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 157 nsec per loop
$ # .search looks at every position, even if there is an anchor
$ python -m timeit --setup "import re; p=re.compile('a'); string='x'*100000" "p.search(string)"
10000 loops, best of 5: 22.4 usec per loop
$ # and the anchor only adds complexity to the matching process
$ python -m timeit --setup "import re; p=re.compile('^a'); string='x'*100000" "p.search(string)"
500 loops, best of 5: 746 usec per loop
```

While `re` does not optimize for anchors, it *does* optimize for several other things that could occur at the start of a pattern. One of those optimizations is for a pattern [starting with a single constant character](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.2/Modules/sre_lib.h#L1422):

```c
    if (prefix_len == 1) {
        /* pattern starts with a literal character */
        SRE_CHAR c = (SRE_CHAR) prefix[0];
#if SIZEOF_SRE_CHAR < 4
        if ((SRE_CODE) c != prefix[0])
            return 0; /* literal can't match: doesn't fit in char width */
#endif
        end = (SRE_CHAR *)state->end;
        state->must_advance = 0;
        while (ptr < end) {
            while (*ptr != c) {
                if (++ptr >= end)
                    return 0;
            }
            ...
```

This optimization performs a simple character comparison to skip candidate matches that don't start with the required character, instead of invoking the full match engine. This optimization is why the unanchored regex was so much faster - there are 3 separate optimizations like this in the code, one for a single constant character, one for a multi-character constant prefix, and one for a character class, but nothing for a `^` anchor.

I think a reasonable case can be made to file a bug report against this - not having such an obvious optimization implemented clearly violates expectations. Aside from which, while it's easy to replace `.search` with an anchor using `.match`, it's not so straightforward to replace `.sub` with an anchor - you have to `.match`, check the result, and then call `.replace` on the string yourself.

If you need to anchor to the *end* of the string *and not* the start, it gets much more difficult; I recall ancient Perl advice to try reversing the string first, but it's hard in general to write a pattern that matches the reverse of what you want.

Comment: 100000 chars in 22.4 usec... that's 4.5 billion chars per second. How fast is your CPU?

Comment: In other words, I suspect it's optimized to search for the first pattern character with `memchr` or so. I might've read that before, not sure

Comment: _"The functions provided in the Python `re` module do not optimize based on the pattern."_ That's very helpful to know! The slowdown for the `^a` pattern is still strange since slowdown for example for the pattern `a$` is almost negligible.

Comment: @Jeyekomon That `a$` result fits the `memchr` theory.

Comment: It looks like `sub` [uses `search`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Modules/_sre.c#L1119) under the hood and there is no reason for `search` to be optimized for the `\A` anchor since in that case one could use `match` instead.

Comment: "100000 chars in 22.4 usec... that's 4.5 billion chars per second." Hmm, you have a point. I think I have something wrong in the explanation. A proper answer will probably require a dive into the C source underlying the `re` module (it hides the details in `_sre`).

Comment: Ah, I see. Although I only have 1600MHz DDR3 RAM in this thing, `memchr` can build a mask and consider 8 bytes at a time on a 64-bit architecture. So checking 4.5B chars/s is not an impossible result.

Comment: Oh, sorry if you thought I meant it's impossible. What I meant is that something like memchr is the only thing I know that makes such speed possible. And that that seems to be used when the first pattern char is an ordinary char like `a` but not when it's `^`.

Comment: I wonder if it considers the length of the string before deciding to incur the setup cost for that.

Comment: *"it's easy to replace `.search` with an anchor using `.match`"* ... if you know that your pattern has that anchor. Like when you hardcoded one pattern. But if you for example iterate over a collection of patterns, some of which have that anchor and others don't... you'd need some code to detect whether you can use `.match` instead of `.search`. And it's not even as trivial as checking whether the pattern string starts with `^`, as it might appear only later in the pattern (for example because of parentheses in front of it or because it's the second option in an alternation).

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica Given the speed of 4.5 gigachars/second (even 5.2 in the OP's timing, presumably faster than their CPU speed), I guess that that loop isn't even the end of the story, but that the C-compiler optimizes that to some CPU instructions testing multiple bytes at once, like what Karl also mentioned earlier about memchr. I don't know how to find that out, though :-)